# describe-package commentary for non built-in packages

Tags: package, package-development

Currently, it seems like `describe-package` will only show the contents of the 'commentary' section for packages that are builtin. For example `(describe-package 'python)` show a detailed description of the package, however `(describe-package 'persp-mode)` only shows the small amount of meta data present for all packages. This despite the fact that it has a "Commentary" section: [link](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el/blob/master/persp-mode.el#L29)

Reading the source of package.el, this seems to be intentional: [package.el link](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el#L2383), however the GNU docs certainly suggest that the usage of the commentary section as the long description is not specific to built-in packages. Specifically, "If the file has a ‘;;; Commentary:’ section, this section is used as the long description."

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Congrats, you found something to report a bug for.  Use `M-x report-emacs-bug` and point out that whatever the assumption behind that code was, it's no longer valid as external packages can be located just fine in your Emacs session.

Comment: `(describe-package 'persp-mode)` displays Commentary section for me on 24.5.1, it will disappear if I install this package and then delete `~/.emacs.d/elpa/persp-mode-readme.txt` manually. Melpa provides this readme file at http://melpa.org/packages/persp-mode-readme.txt I am using Gnu Elpa and Melpa.